# Files not visible on MTP mount, but visible in adb shell

Tags: file-system, linux, file-transfer, mtp

To offload some media files from my phone, I connected it to my (Linux) PC through USB, and set it to file transfer mode (MTP) so that the internal storage gets mounted. I see many files, which I can copy without a problem, but there are also many files that I don't see at all on my PC.

Exploring the file system with "adb shell", there turn out to be many more files in the same file system.

Does anyone know why they don't show up and what I can do about it? The file permissions seem to be the same as those of the visible files.

Thanks.

Comment: Anything those "invisible files" have in common the "visible ones" don't have – e.g. file type or "file name pattern"? And as you're using the `linux` tag, would you be open to solutions other than MTP (I'm thinking of user-space `adbfs` here, which maps the file system transparently and is, to my experience, much more reliable)?

Comment: I'll check out adbfs, thanks! For now I just used "adb pull". I didn't see any pattern, but I'll have a closer look.

Comment: Check out [my ADB list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb#group_947), it mentions some items in this context. I'm personally using `adbfs-rootless`, but it currently has an issue with some Nougat ROMs unfortunately. So [aafm](https://github.com/sole/aafm) (a Python based ADB file manager) might be a good choice, or one of the general GUI tools like [QtADB](https://qtadb.wordpress.com/).